# How can I calculate the distinct count of a customerID during the last six months DAX? I need to see if customers have transactions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a table in my database that creates records based on customers billing.

[image]

I decided to create a rolling calendar and add a relationship to the table, where my customer IDs are located. I have tried to find the count of ID records with:

```
Customer Base =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Ddcca[Clienteid] ),
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( Ddcca[Clienteid] ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            Rolling_Calendar[Date],
            DATEADD ( STARTOFMONTH ( Rolling_Calendar[Date] ), -6, MONTH ),
            STARTOFMONTH ( Rolling_Calendar[Date] )
        )
    ),
    MAXX (
        VALUES ( Rolling_Calendar[Date] ),
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( Ddcca[Clienteid] ),
            DATESBETWEEN (
                Rolling_Calendar[Date],
                DATEADD ( STARTOFMONTH ( Rolling_Calendar[Date] ), -17, MONTH ),
                STARTOFMONTH ( Rolling_Calendar[Date] )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

My rolling calendar includes non repeating dates, when I try to create a matrix in powerBI I get  error:

*Cant display visual*

.

[Rolling calendar connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aqxc.png)

[Rolling calendar is up to todays date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10FON.png)

Comment: Please post an image of your rolling calendar table, and explain how you connect it to the main table.

Comment: I just posted the images you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

First create the continues date table separately. Then connect the dates table to your current table, and it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you told powerBi the date table is a date dimension?
I generally find i have more luck getting help if i create a simple example in powerbi, save it to oneDrive/Google Drive and paste the link along with the question. 
Its can take a bit of time, but there are usually more answers and they are of higher quality.

[image]